# How to perform a date range filter on string with LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am trying to do a date range filter using the following linq:

```
IQueryable<Movies> movies= _context.Movies
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Select(i => i);

DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(searchStartDate);
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(searchEndDate);

movies = movies.Where(i => Convert.ToDateTime(i.TransDate) >= startDate &&
                Convert.ToDateTime(i.TransDate) <= endDate)
                .OrderByDescending(j => j.Id);
```

But it is't working and is giving me InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '...' could not be translated.

NOTE: The database I was given to work with has TransDate column in string format('YYYY-MM-DD'), hence this question.

Comment: Why would you store a date as a string in a database ?

Comment: If your date in not a string in the database then just remove `Convert.ToDateTime` in the query. If it is however, change your database

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for the database table.

Comment: I wish it was stored as datetime in database too but unfortunately, I wasn't the one to  create the database.

Comment: What is the format it is stored in in the database?

Comment: The "TransDate" is stored as a string / character varying(20) in the format: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Then don't convert the data in the database to a date - just use string comparisons. `movies = movies.Where(i => i.TransDate  >= "2000-01-01" )  && i.TransDate < "2000-01-03")).OrderByDescending(j => j.Id);` will get you all records for 1st and 2nd of January 2000. _I mean, it would be better if you fixed your database schema - but if you can't do that, my suggestion will work._

Comment: BTW, some of the answers suggest continuing to try converting the strings (in the database) to a date **at query time** (e.g. `CreateDateTime`). I would encourage you _not_ to do this since it will wreck sargability.

Comment: @mjwills I don't think you can compare strings like that right?

Comment: @AaronYong Ah, good call. Does `string.Compare` work? _Be sure to do a SQL Trace and check the actual SQL passing over the wire._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While storing dates as string in database is not a good idea, at least the chosen  format is orderable. And while EF Core does not provide translatable method for converting string to date, it allows you to have entity property of type `DateTime` (as it should have been), and map it to string column in database using [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions). Thus, you would write query against `DateTime`, and EF Core will convert the constant/parameter values to string and pass them to the SQL query.

Applying it to your case:

*Model:*

```cs
public class Movie
{
    // other properties...

    public DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```cs
const string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(e => e.TransDate)
    .HasConversion(
        dateValue => dateValue.ToString(DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        stringValue => DateTime.ParseExact(stringValue, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    )
    .IsRequired()
    .IsUnicode(false) // arbitrary
    .HasMaxLength(10); // arbitrary
```

*LINQ query usage:*

```cs
IQueryable<Movie> movies = ...;
DateTime startDate = ...;
DateTime endDate = ...;

movies = movies
    .Where(e => e.TransDate >= startDate && e.TransDate <= endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing one `OrderByDescending` you already have ordered it in the first statement. You are ordering the same query twice.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem, you'll have to be aware of the differences between IEnumerable and IQueryable.

### IEnumerable

An object of a class that implements `IEnumerable<...>` represents a sequence of similar objects. It holds everything to get the first element of the sequence, and as long as you've got an element, you can try to get the next one.

At its lowest level, this is done using `GetEnumerator` and repeatedly calling `MoveNext() / Current`, like this:

```
IEnumerable<Movie> movies = ...
IEnumerator<Movie> enumerator = movies.GetEnumerator();

// try to get the next element:
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // There is a next element
    Movie movie = enumerator.Current;
    ProcessMovie(movie);
}
```

Deep inside `foreach` will do something like this. Every LINQ method that doesn't return `IEnumerable<...>` will also deep inside call `GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current`.

An IEnumerable is meant to be executed by your process, hence the IEnumerable has access to all your procedures.

### IQueryable

Although an IQueryable looks like an IEnumerable, it represent **the potential** to get an enumerable sequence.

For this, the IQueryable has an Expression and a Provider. The Expression holds what data must be fetched in some generic format; the Provider knows where he must fetch the data (Usually a database management system), and what language to use when fetching the data (usually SQL).

As long as you concatenate LINQ methods that return `IQueryable<...>` the Expression changes. The query is not executed, the database is not contacted. We say that the LINQ method uses deferred execution, or lazy execution. Concatenating such LINQ statements is not expensive.

The LINQ methods that don't return `IQueryable<...>`, like ToList(), ToDictionary(), FirstOrDefault(), Count(), Any(), are the expensive ones, just like foreach they will deep inside call GetEnumerator().

When you call `GetEnumerator()`, the Expression is sent to the Provider, who will translate the Expression into SQL and execute the Query. The fetched data is returned as an `IEnumerator<...>` of which you can call `MoveNext() / Current`.

Some Providers are smarter than others. For instance, some of them will not fetch the data  when you get the Enumerator, but fetch it at the first MoveNext. Others won't fetch all requested data at once, but fetch the data "per page", so if you decide to enumerate only two or three items, then only the first page of Movies are fetched, not all 10000 of them.

### But what has this to do with my question?

You use a method that your Provider doesn't know: `Convert.ToDateTime`. Hence it can't translate it into SQL. In fact, there are several LINQ methods that are not supported by entity framework. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Your compiler doesn't know how smart the Provider is, so your compiler can't complain. You'll get your error at runtime.

So you can't use `Convert.ToDateTime`, nor methods like `Datetime.Parse`.

### What to do?

You wrote that the strings that you want to convert are in format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
What you could do, is use string handling routines to separate them into "YYYY", "MM" and "DD". It depends on your provider whether you can use `String.SubString`.

Then use class [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) to [CreateDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createdatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbFunctions_CreateDateTime_System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Nullable_System_Double__)

```
.Where(x => ... && DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(
      x.TransDate.SubString(0,4),               // YYYY
      x.TransDate.SubString(5, 2),              // MM
      x.TransDate.SubString(8, 2),              // DD
      0, 0, 0) < endDate;
```

If your Provider also doesn't accept SubString, search for other methods to extract the YYYY, MM and DD. I know [Sqlite has a Date](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-date-function#:%7E:text=The%20SQLite%20date()%20function,the%20values%20in%20following%20formats.) method to convert strings to DateTime.

If you can't find any proper string manipulation routines, consider to convert endDate into format "YYYY-MM-DD" and return compare the TransDate string with the endDateSTring

```
string endDateString = String.Format("{0:D04}-{1:D02}-{2:D02}", endDate.Year, endDate.Month, ...)
```

Fiddle a bit with it, until you've got the correct format. Then use:

```
.Where(x => ... && x.TransDate < endDateString)
```

If that also does not work, create the SQL query yourself.